# Facing trouble in installing PyAudio

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio

I am trying to make Jarvis like program But getting the Error

> AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

```
import speech_recognition
import pyttsx3

speech_engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
speech_engine.setProperty('rate', 150)

def speak(text):
    speech_engine.say(text)
    speech_engine.runAndWait()

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

def listen():
    with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)

    try:
        return recognizer.recognize_sphinx(audio)
        # or: return recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
    except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
        print("Could not understand audio")
    except speech_recognition.RequestError as e:
        print("Recog Error; {0}".format(e))

    return ""

speak("Say something!")
speak("I heard you say " + listen())
```

I have tried to install pyaudio but getting error in its installation

```
pip install pipwin

pipwin install pyaudio
```

Installation error

> File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1336, in _RealGetContents
>       raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
>   zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Comment: did you try to download the wheel from Gohlke and install it via pip?

Comment: And this is example of XY problem - clearly you have trouble installing PyAudio. Which in turn leads to the AttributeError you refer to. Ask the right question.

Comment: no! I am using it for the first time please tell me how to do it

Comment: download PyAudio for your systemt from here https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio That is what pipwin is doing for you. Then run `pip install path_to_wheel\pyaudio_wheel.whl`. Of course replace `path_to_wheel\pyaudio_wheel.whl` with actual path and file name

Answer (score 0):

Go to [this](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) link and find PyAudio and then download one for your python version.

Then open a powershell window in your downloads folder and type:-

```
pip install PyAu
```

and then press <kbd>tab</kbd>, it will autocomplete and the press <kbd>enter</kbd>.